# JSON:API Matching Collections with its respective Includes

Tags: node.js, json, express, json-api, jsonapi-resources

What exactly is the best practice for matching JSON:API data collections with their respective includes. Considering  the following code below....

What if I wanted to loop through each venue and display the Owners full information for each Venue Record. Does JSON:API expect me to  just search the  include  array  for the matching Owner Record

```
find(included,data[$i].relationships.owner.data.id);
```

Would `find()` loop through the   included array  to  look  for the  owner  that has  the  matching id as the collection items  owner in the relationships  object ?

```
$(data).each(function(item){
var owner = find(included,'owner', item.relationships.owner.data.id)
})
```

I have not found a resource that explains this or perhapes I am mis understanding the point  of json:api. If someone can explain this or point to a resource that relates to my question. I would  appreciate it.

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://127.0.0.1/api/venues?include=owner"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "5c5b49188fd33c7a989ba9b6",
      "type": "venues",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Kreiger - Smith",
        "address": "69675 Reilly Vista",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -112.110492,
            36.098948
          ]
        },
        "events": [
          {
            "_id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6",
            "name": "Cool Awesome Event!",
            "user": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
            "id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.207Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.207Z"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "owner": {
          "data": {
            "id": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
            "type": "users"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5c5b49188fd33c7a989ba9b7",
      "type": "venues",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Oberbrunner Inc",
        "address": "1132 Kenyon Stravenue",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -112.110492,
            36.098948
          ]
        },
        "events": [
          {
            "_id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6",
            "name": "Cool Awesome Event!",
            "user": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
            "id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.207Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.207Z"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "owner": {
          "data": {
            "id": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
            "type": "users"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5c5b49188fd33c7a989ba9b8",
      "type": "venues",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Gibson - Muller",
        "address": "8457 Hailie Canyon",
        "location": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -112.110492,
            36.098948
          ]
        },
        "events": [
          {
            "_id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6",
            "name": "Cool Awesome Event!",
            "user": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
            "id": "ad52825a8f4812e92f87b8c6"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.208Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-07T14:27:13.208Z"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "owner": {
          "data": {
            "id": "a1881c06eec96db9901c7bbf",
            "type": "users"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "b3daa77b4c04a9551b8781d0",
      "type": "users",
      "attributes": {
        "username": "killerjohn",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Chapman"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "a1881c06eec96db9901c7bbf",
      "type": "users",
      "attributes": {
        "username": "numerical25",
        "firstname": "Billy",
        "lastname": "Gordon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## This is my best possible solution. But is there a better way ? Seems like alot more coding just to find a collections associated included data

```
  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/venues?include=owner').then(function(response) {
    var  venues = response.data.data;
    var data = response.data;
    for(x in venues) {
      var owner = data.included.find(function(element) {
        if(element.id == venues[x].relationships.owner.data.id) {
          return element;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: You are missing the "." after data[$i]relationships -> data[$i].relationships. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Its a typo. But the question isnt about the syntax. Its  about the best practices for mapping a collection of includes with  the respective main data collection

Comment: what I wrote was nothing but psuedo. Its been  fixed though

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Especially it's unclear what you are comparing it to if talking about "a lot more coding". You may not want to deal with the response directly if it comes to more complex stuff like relationships but represent that data trough a store? You may want to check out existing implementations: https://jsonapi.org/implementations/

Comment: Don't know if you ever found an answer to this but it looks like there's a package on that implementations page for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-api-merge. I just discovered it as well.